# bash command for group by count

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file in the following format

```
abc|1
def|2
abc|8
def|3
abc|5
xyz|3
```

I need to group by these words in the first column and sum the value of the second column. For instance, the output of this file should be

```
abc|14
def|5
xyz|3
```

Explanation: the corresponding values for word "abc" are 1, 8, and 5. By adding these numbers, the sum comes out to be 14 and the output becomes "abc|14". Similarly, for word "def", the corresponding values are 2 and 3. Summing up these, the final output comes out to be "def|5".

Thank you very much for the help :)

I tried the following command

```
awk -F "|" '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i"|"arr[i]}}' filename
```

another command which I found was

```
awk -F "," 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","}{arr[$1]+=$2 }END {for (i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' filename
```

Both didn't show me the intended results. Although I'm also in doubt of the working of these commands as well.

Comment: What did you try for yourself? There are countless answers of similar type, did you look at them before?

Comment: I have no clue about how to do this, tried various results on google, but with no luck

Comment: Can you post the results you attempted into the question?

Comment: I have made the changes in the questions. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: What is wrong with the first command (`awk -F "|" '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i"|"arr[i]}}' filename
`), seems to work!

Comment: oh yes! thank you so much. It's working. I made a very silly mistake. I provided a sorted file, but the output of this wasn't sorted. I got confused with the output. Thanks @Inian for stating the command is correct. I used the sort | uniq after the above provided command, it worked. Thank you once again for pointing out. :)

Comment: You could also set output de-limiter to `|` by using `OFS` variable, like, `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{unique[$1]+=$2; next}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' file`, so that you don't have to use that while printing

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I now got to explore this variable as well as other variables which are used so that I can improve. Thank you Inian once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will just add an answer to fix the sorting issue you had, in your `Awk` logic, you don't need to use `sort`/`uniq` piped to the output of `Awk`, but process in `Awk` itself.

Referring to [GNU `Awk` Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders with `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html), you can use the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` variable(`gawk` specific)  to control how you want `Awk` to sort your final output.

Referring to the section below,

> `@ind_str_asc`
>   Order by indices in ascending order compared as strings; this is the most basic sort. (Internally, array indices are always strings, so with `a[2*5] = 1` the index is `10` rather than numeric `10`.)

So using this in your requirement in the `END` clause just do,

```
END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}
```

with your full command being,

```
awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{
        unique[$1]+=$2; 
        next
    }
    END{
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; 
        for (i in unique) 
            print i,unique[i]
    }' file
```

Comment: @Inian , can this command be modified in such a way that if there is a third column of integers ? 
ABC | 10 | 20
ABC | 20 | 30
Output : ABC | 30 | 50

Answer (score 4):

Short GNU [***datamash***](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) solution:

```
datamash -s -t\| -g1 sum 2 < filename
```

The output:

```
abc|14
def|5
xyz|3
```

---

- `-t\|` - field separator
- `-g1` - group by the 1st column
- `sum 2` - sum up values of the 2nd column

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F\| '{ arry[$1]+=$2 } END { asorti(arry,arry2);for (i in arry2) { print arry2[i]"|"arry[arry2[i]]} }' filename
```

Your initial solution should work apart from the issue with sort. Use asorti function to sort the indices from arry to arry2 and then process these in the loop.