# Bash group by on the basis of n number of columns

Tags: bash, shell, awk

This is related to my previous question that I [asked] ([bash command for group by count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45709687/bash-command-for-group-by-count/))

What if I want to generalize this? For instance
The input file is

```
 ABC|1|2
 ABC|3|4
 BCD|7|2
 ABC|5|6
 BCD|3|5
```

The output should be

```
 ABC|9|12
 BCD|10|7
```

The result is calculated by group first column and adding the values of 2nd column, and 3rd column, just like similar to group by command in SQL.

I tried modifying the command provided in the link but failed. I don't know whether I'm making a conceptual error or a silly mistake but all I know is none of the mentioned commands aren't working.

Command used

```
awk -F "|" '{arr[$1]+=$2} END arr2[$1]+=$5 END  {for (i in arr) {print i"|"arr[i]"|"arr2[i]}}' sample
awk -F "|" '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {arr2[$1]+=$5} END  {for (i in arr) {print i"|"arr[i]"|"arr2[i]}}' sample
 awk -F "|" '{arr[$1]+=$2 arr2[$1]+=$5} END  {for (i in arr2) {print i"|"arr[i]"|"arr2[i]}}' sample
```

Additionally, what if I'm trying here is to limit the use to summing the columns upto 2 only. What if there are n columns and we want to perform operations such as addition in one column and subtraction in other? How can that further be modified?

Example

```
ABC|1|2|4|......... upto n columns
ABC|4|5|6|......... upto n columns
DEF|1|4|6|......... upto n columns
```

lets say if sum is needed with first column, average may be for second column, some other operation for third column, etc. How this can be tackled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 3 fields (key and 2 data fields):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }      # set separators
{ 
    a[$1]+=$2             # sum second field to a hash
    b[$1]+=$3             # ... b hash
}
END {                     # in the end
    for(i in a)           # loop all
        print i,a[i],b[i] # and output
}' file
BCD|10|7
ABC|9|12
```

More generic solution for *n* columns using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)                    # loop all data fields
        a[$1][i]+=$i                      # sum them up to related cells
    a[$1][1]=i                            # set field count to first cell
}
END {
    for(i in a) {
        for((j=2)&&b="";j<a[i][1];j++)    # buffer output
            b=b (b==""?"":OFS)a[i][j]
        print i,b                         # output
    }
}' file
BCD|10|7
ABC|9|12
```

Latter only tested for 2 fields (busy at a meeting :).

Comment: thanks, @James, I got the logic behind your script. If there's some issue I'll update with solution or approach you for solution. Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Your `for` loop could be quite a bit simpler: `for (j=2;j<=NF;j++) b=(j>2?b OFS:"") a[i][j]`. Also, you don't need `a[$1][1]=i` unless you expect there to be different numbers of fields on every line which I highly doubt and the OP would've told us about...

Answer (score 2):

***gawk*** approach using multidimensional array:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }{ a[$1]["f2"]+=$2; a[$1]["f3"]+=$3 }
     END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i]["f2"],a[i]["f3"] }' file
```

- `a[$1]["f2"]+=$2` - summing up values of the 2nd field (`f2` - field 2)
- `a[$1]["f3"]+=$3` - summing up values of the 3rd field (`f3` - field 3)

---

The output:

```
ABC|9|12
BCD|10|7
```

---

Additional short ***datamash*** solution (will give the same output):

```
datamash -st\| -g1 sum 2 sum 3 <file
```

- `-s` - sort the input lines
- `-t\|` - field separator
- `sum 2 sum 3` - sums up values of the 2nd and 3rd fields respectively

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F\| '{ array[$1]="";for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { arr[$1,i]+=$i }  } END { for (i in array) { printf "%s",i;for (p=2;p<=NF;p++) { printf "|%s",arr[i,p] } print "\n" } }' filename
```

We use two arrays, (array and arr) array is a single dimensional array tracking all the first pieces and arr is a multidimensional array keyed on the first piece and then the piece index and so for example arr["ABC",1]=1 and arr["ABC",2]=2. At the end we loop through array and then each field in the data set, we pull out the data from the multidimensional array arr.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in any awk and will retain the input keys order in the output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
!seen[$1]++ { keys[++numKeys] = $1 }
{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        sum[$1,i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        printf "%s%s", key, OFS
        for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sum[key,i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ABC|9|12
BCD|10|7
```